# VSCode throws error when setting PATH environment variable in devcontainer.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the following `devcontainer.json` file in a project.

When I try to open VSCode in a container, it crashes. The container builds successfully, but the following logs are emitted during startup. When I remove the environment variable configuration, the container starts up and stays running just fine.

I followed the example for configuring environment variables inside the dev container, according to the Visual Studio Code documentation for [Advanced Container Configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced).

**Question**: How do I properly configure the `PATH` environment variable in my `devcontainer.json` file?

#### devcontainer.json

```
{
    "name": "Ubuntu 18.04 & Git",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
    "settings": { 
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
    },
    "containerEnv": {
        "PATH": "${containerEnv:PATH}:/root/.customfolder/bin/"
    }
}
```

#### Logs

```
6499 ms] Successfully built 096d41dceada
[6503 ms] Successfully tagged vsc-asdf-73cee28d5205fdd4a6063fc596248885:latest
[6506 ms] Start: Run: git rev-parse --show-toplevel
[6533 ms] Start: Starting container
[6533 ms] Start: Run: docker run -a STDOUT -a STDERR --mount type=bind,source=/Users/username/git/asdf,target=/workspaces/asdf,consistency=cached --mount source=/Users/username/.aws/credentials,target=/root/.aws/credentials,type=bind -l vsch.quality=stable -l vsch.remote.devPort=0 -l vsch.local.folder=/Users/username/git/asdf -e PATH=${containerEnv:PATH}:/root/.customfolder/bin/ --entrypoint /bin/sh vsc-pulumi-73cee28d5205fdd4a6063fc596248885 -c echo Container started ; while sleep 1; do :; done
[6852 ms] /bin/sh: 1: sleep: not found
[6852 ms] Container started
[6873 ms] Start: Inspecting container
[6879 ms] Start: Run in container: uname -m
[7031 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /etc/passwd
[7035 ms] Shell server terminated (code: 1, signal: null)

Error response from daemon: Container 8e0f6eeb22c358b0dfd8f1c1410c10b382ea66aa432e7e400a4564671619046f is not running
```

[image: An error occurred setting up the container]

> An error occurred setting up the container

#### Environment

- MacOS Catalina
- Docker Desktop 2.2.0.0
- Microsoft Visual Studio Code 1.42.0
- VSCode Remote-Containers extension 0.101.0

Comment: For what its worth, I am having issues after upgrading to VS Code 1.42.0 with one of my dev containers. I get a similar error. This container previously worked fine. This is on Ubuntu Eoan with Docker CE 19.03.3~3-0~ubuntu-disco.


    [6453 ms] Start: Inspecting container
    [6457 ms] Start: Run in container: uname -m
    [6584 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /etc/passwd
    [6588 ms] Shell server terminated (code: 137, signal: null)

Comment: After further testing it seems like it was caused by the "CMD" option I was using in the Dockerfile (not sure why it worked before). I removed the option completely and my dev container now works.

Comment: @shthead Hmmmm, I don't have a `CMD` instruction in my `Dockerfile` at all. Thanks for sharing either way though.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to change the property from `containerEnv` to `remoteEnv` to resolve the issue.

Only the `remoteEnv` property supports referencing existing container env vars.  The `containerEnv` property is like `-e` for the Docker CLI and is therefore evaluated before the container is created.  This is mainly useful when your Dockerfile itself depends on certain env vars being set (though you can modify the PATH inside your Dockerfile if you so desire).

For everything else, `remoteEnv` is the way to go since VS Code and all sub-processes like terminals us it. Since this is evaluated after container create, you can update the path as the examples illustrates.

```
"remoteEnv": {
    "PATH": "${containerEnv:PATH}:/some/other/path",
    "MY_REMOTE_VARIABLE": "some-other-value-here",
    "MY_REMOTE_VARIABLE2": "${localEnv:SOME_LOCAL_VAR}"
}
```

Comment: My `Dockerfile` does depend on the env var being set, so it sounds like `containerEnv` is in theory the right way to go, per your description. However, because `containerEnv` works like `-e`, I can't append to the container's `$PATH`. Hence, I will need to use one of my work-arounds.

Answer (score 0):

```json
"containerEnv": {
        "PATH": "${localEnv:PATH}:/workspaces/v8/depot_tools"
}
```

I think that is what you need. `localEnv` here means the container env.